# How to export or make a chart Apply Family of functions in R

Tags: r, apply, xts, quantmod

```
require("quantmod")
getSymbols("AAPL")
apply.yearly(AAPL[,1], mean)

          AAPL.Open
2007-12-31  128.3891
2008-12-31  142.3138
2009-12-31  146.6191
2010-12-31  259.9576
2011-12-30  364.0614
2012-12-31  576.6527
2013-12-31  473.1281
2014-12-31  295.1426
2015-09-30  122.1547
```

I'd like to be able to present these results to someone: How do I export the results? I can do it with something like knitR and Rmarkdown into a report, but I'd like to be able to do a fast export.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on what exactly you mean by "fast export".  If you want something that you can paste into an email quickly and have it look nice, your best bet is probably `Hmisc::html`, which will save to a file and pop it up in a web browser, where you can copy the table somewhere else.

If you're looking for a data export (so that someone can put it into Excel or similar) then you can just use `write.csv` to write out a csv with the results, and send that file.

Comment: I get this error. Im on Mac OS: Error in paste(browser, object, if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") "&") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: @Rhodo - can you show the command you ran to get that message?

Comment: apply.yearly(AAPL[,1], mean)